# How to download video file from vimeo basic user account using Vimeo API application

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, download, vimeo

i'm developing iOS application for some kind of video processing.
This application should download videos from different sources (it already works with photo stream, iPod library and external files). Now i'm trying to implement downloading video files from user's Vimeo feed.
i've created Vimeo API application, implemented authentication and implemented reading data from /me/feed (using VIMNetworking for iOS). Data (in JSON format mapped to VIMVideo objects) are successfully loaded and video information (name, creation time, thumbnail picture and so on ...) are successfully displayed in application's UICollectionView. But VideoFiles collection in VIMVideo object is nil. When i've tested my app in Vimeo API Playground this VideoFiles collection is also absent in JSON output. But native Vimeo iOS application can download video files from my Vimeo feed for local playback under my basic account so the account is not the restriction!

The question is:

how native Vimeo iOS application does file download from user's Vimeo feed and how can i implement the same functionality in my iOS app using Vimeo API (using VIMNetworking)?

Kind regards,
Alexey

Answer (score 0):

i've found the answer myself here:
[Get direct Vimeo video url Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042573/get-direct-vimeo-video-url-android)

I've got links for files from JSON is returned by GET request `https://player.vimeo.com/video/<video_id>/config`

Native iOS Vimeo app doesn't work this way.
I've try to trace it via Charles Web Debugging Proxy http://www.charlesproxy.com

Unfortunately native iOS Vimeo app is protected with pinned cert from the 'man-in-middle' so i can't see the content of the `api.vimeo.com` requests but can see others (one way to pass the protection is to remove the `digicert-sha2.cer` file from the app bundle and resign the app with my own developer or ad-hoc cert, but all my attempts were failed). Also i've analyzed the cache information stored in the native iOS Vimeo app.

In both cases i've not seen requests to `https://player.vimeo.com/video/<video_id>/config` from Vimeo app so this feature is undocumented.

I hope Vimeo will open (document) the valid way to get files links for downloading video.