# Get high-res Vimeo file URL

Tags: video, html5-video, vimeo

Is there a recommended way to get the vimeo file path to the original (full resolution) video with a PRO-account?

I uploaded a video in 3840x1080 which I try to embed with a custom player.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042573/get-direct-vimeo-video-url-android) Andrew F mentions a API link which seems not to be supported by vimeo. Furthermore I don't get the required information when requesting the API (the `files` entry is missing).

I contacted the vimeo support but didn't receive an answer yet.

I can access the file links via the vimeo settings screen, but the links for embedding are limited to 1920x540. However I get the full-resolution link as download link (https://player.vimeo.com/external/xxxxxxxx.source.mp4?s=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&profile_id=0&download=1). Can I use this URI for embedding aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/VIDEOID` I get all the information I need