# how to access unlisted vimeo videos in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, vimeo

i want to display unlisted vimeo video in flutter and i have used many packages to show the video and its not working !

i have used many packages to show the video and its not working
i just tried vimeo_video_player , vimeoplayer_trinity , vimeo_player_flutter
the error message :

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:203)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:114)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1005)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:289)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:152)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:184)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       ... 8 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8046)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25834):       ... 11 more
E/flutter (25834): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

Comment: first confirm you get mp4 url or not  see refrence - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042573/get-direct-vimeo-video-url-android

Comment: because all vimeo library use this url and get mp4 url but some vimeo video can't provide mp4 url

Comment: @SachinKumawat https://vimeo.com/820827635/36227ad03e?share=copy this the video url

Comment: check this video private or public because can't find video with video id

Comment: 809305521 this is demo vimeo id and play with this url -  https://vimeo.com/<vimeo_id>  like https://vimeo.com/809305521 and your video id - 820827635 and can't find video with this url - https://vimeo.com/820827635

Comment: ok but how to access unlisted video with just id ?

Comment: Vimeo might have changed the path/format of unlisted video URLs. I'm no longer with the company so I don't have a recommendation, try contacting their support: https://vimeo.com/help/contact